# SD card module with ESP32

Tags: esp32, sd, module, read

I'm using an SD card module with ESP32. My plan is to store configurations such as SSID and passwords.

I tried the function with a text file which contains the text "Hello" and for `Serial.write(file.read());` it prints exactly "Hello". But, `Serial.print(file.read());` returns 72101108108111. What kind of data type returns `read()`? I need to convert it into string.

```
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Read from file: ");
  while(file.available()){
    //Serial.write(file.read());
    Serial.print(file.read());
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: Well what does some sort of manual say about what serial.print() does? I can't even guess what framework you are using, is that Arduino or something else?

Comment: `Serial.print((char)file.read());`

Answer (score 1):

That's decimal values of the characters `Hello`.

`72` is decimal for `H`
`101` is decimal for `e`
`108` is decimal for `l`
`111` is decimal for `o`
See any ascii chart on the internet, eg. This [Ascii Chart](https://www.alpharithms.com/ascii-table-512119/)

Maybe try something like this instead:
`Serial.printf("%s\n", file.read());`

**UPDATE:**
As noted in the comments, doing a cast is more memory efficient than using printf().
So `Serial.print( (char)file.read() );` 
and you can also use streams:
`Serial<<(char)file.read();`

Comment: An explicit conversion to `char` is preferable because `printf()` uses lots of program memory... see dandavis' comment. It might not be a big deal on an ESP32, but using `printf()` on an Arduino Uno is close to a no-go ;)

Comment: Doing a cast  won’t work as the array of bytes is not null terminated. The streams method is a better and more robust solution.